# Connecting multiple debuggers to a debugee (Java,JPDA)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Ive been trying unsuccessfully to connect two client debuggers to 
a Debuggee program in context of JPDA. Is this possible or
are there workarounds to make it happen?

I am using eclipse as the IDE (edit for typo).
Think of a server program as a Hello World 
which Prints out:

```
System.out.println("I have the String"); //1
System.out.println("You will have to pass through the breakpoints before you shall see");
System.out.println("breakpoints");
System.out.println("before you shall see"); //4
```

We can put breakpoints  at lines 1 and 4.

Step 1:
The params passed to the program in Run Configuration:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y
```

(`server=y` tells vm to behave like a server, `suspend=y` implies that prog execution will be suspended till debugger latches on to it)
and Run the program.

Step 2: Go to `Debug as , Debug config ,Remote Java application` and
create a new instance:

```
Project: Same as before
Connection type: Socket Attach(Socket Attach)
Host:LocalHost
Port:8000
```

Now when I debug Prog execution stops at the specified breakpoint.
What I cant do is create another instance of this remote debugger that
can latch on to the server(prog 1), I get a connection refused when I do that. Let me know if anyone else has faced this problem
and if a workaround exists.
Thanks!

Thanks

Comment: If it is doable (which I really think it isn't) it wouldn't make much sense except for situations where one debugger acted as a master and the others just followed it to view how the process stopped at breakpoints, caught exceptions etc. (At least I can't think of a good use but I am interested to learn more)

Comment: fwiw, having the separate views, like you describe, seems useful to me. It would be really nice to open a few separate jdb windows when debugging with jdb, one for control, one to watch some variables, one to watch the stack trace, etc. This would allow command-line debugging to be more similar to what Eclipse does with multiple windows.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there can be only one instance of debugger connected to a java program any given time. Once you started you program in debug, Eclipse connects to the debugged program blocking all other connection attempts. If you want to connect remotely you can run the program not in debug mode and add the parameters: 
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y 
to java parameters manually, then you should be able to connect with another debugger.

Comment: well The core idea is to allow debugging of mutually exclusive threads within the same Server process, Tried it manually to get a Connection Refused. Is there a existing protocol that allows listening on a new port if a request comes in at a existing port that is servicing another request?(Edit for Punctuation) Thank you for your comments Yuval and Fredrick.

Comment: Further I came across: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/jpda_spis.html#TransportDev which talks about Developing a TransportService to support multiple concurrent connections to a single listener address. Now another question is has anyone made this or attempted to?

Comment: @javaresearcher keep listening on a port after accepting a connection is not a problem. The problem here is that it would make the whole debugging process extremely unintuitive. A bit like driving a car with three passengers and a set of steering wheels and pedals in front of each seat. Only one would be able to be in control at any given time or things would go terribly wrong. I think it would make more sense if you tried to explain why you are trying to do it. Maybe there is a much better way to do what you want. (edit: see the "core idea" in your top comment now but why two debuggers?)

Comment: @Fredrik, Think cloud. Separate threads, mutually exclusive belonging to  separate entities compartmentalized within a server process, But then each entity wants to debug its own Thread, though essentially it does not know what it is debugging is only a subset, Hope this sheds more light. I would love to hear if better ways exist.

Comment: @javaresearcher I am thinking cloud just about everyday of the week but the debugger you want to use is not even in that picture. Stopping the VM on a breakpoint is not an option in such an environment.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how things were in 2010, but in 2014 this is doable. I'm debugging an applet and a servlet at the same time eventough they use different JVM, to do so just start your remote debug process in eclipse like socket Listen, the start the first java applicaction with:

-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:8787,suspend=y

Then start the same eclipse remote debug process and start another java process with the same options, you should see the processes spawn like this:

[image: debug in eclipse]

You can see the two different JVM listening in the same port (nevermind the name of the 'applet' process)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but it seems that you connect your debugger (Eclipse) to multiple JVMs. The question was about connecting multiple debuggers to the same JVM.